# Node-Red Dashboard. Ui template, update the url using msg.payload

Tags: dashboard, node-red

I need to change the url of ui_template in the dasboard of node-red.
If I write something like:

```
<iframe src="https://online.wonderware.eu/s/l5kctp/Explore/Analysis/loquesea/Embed"></iframe>
```

I can see:
[image]

If I try to send the url using the msg.payload y can see:
[image]

I tried to get the payload with the next code:

```
<iframe src={{msg.payload}}></iframe>
```

And the payload is:

```
msg.payload="https://online.wonderware.eu/s/l5kctp/Explore/Analysis/loquesea/Embed";
```

I tried a lot of sintaxis to read the payload but I can not read it correctly.

Do you know How Can I read the payload and change the ui_template url?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using template node in front of the ui_template. You want to use three curly brackets to escape the HTML.

```
<iframe src={{{payload}}}></iframe>
```

[image]

```
[{"id":"8fbf7029.588de","type":"tab","label":"Flow 1","disabled":false,"info":""},{"id":"dc2dd6a.d014628","type":"inject","z":"8fbf7029.588de","name":"","topic":"","payload":"http://localhost:1880","payloadType":"str","repeat":"","crontab":"","once":false,"onceDelay":"0.5","x":230,"y":220,"wires":[["35a71b83.0fda04"]]},{"id":"c1cf74f3.655238","type":"ui_template","z":"8fbf7029.588de","group":"d2702cb6.ab449","name":"","order":0,"width":"22","height":"12","format":"","storeOutMessages":true,"fwdInMessages":true,"templateScope":"local","x":600,"y":220,"wires":[[]]},{"id":"35a71b83.0fda04","type":"template","z":"8fbf7029.588de","name":"","field":"template","fieldType":"msg","format":"handlebars","syntax":"mustache","template":"<iframe src={{{payload}}}></iframe>","output":"str","x":420,"y":220,"wires":[["c1cf74f3.655238"]]},{"id":"d2702cb6.ab449","type":"ui_group","z":"","name":"G1","tab":"223c13e7.70f2cc","disp":true,"width":"22","collapse":false},{"id":"223c13e7.70f2cc","type":"ui_tab","z":"","name":"T1","icon":"dashboard","disabled":false,"hidden":false}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need some quotes in the template:

```
<iframe src="{{msg.payload}}"></iframe>
```

That should work.

The following flow works as a demo:

```
[{"id":"73ac3c27.dcfd64","type":"tab","label":"Flow 1","disabled":false,"info":""},{"id":"28b66011.fbc02","type":"ui_tab","z":"","name":"Home","icon":"dashboard"},{"id":"99b10eed.f26b","type":"ui_group","z":"","name":"Default","tab":"28b66011.fbc02","disp":true,"width":"6"},{"id":"54e8a488.88e8bc","type":"inject","z":"73ac3c27.dcfd64","name":"","topic":"","payload":"http://localhost:1880","payloadType":"str","repeat":"","crontab":"","once":true,"onceDelay":0.1,"x":200,"y":220,"wires":[["2823261f.a736ea"]]},{"id":"2823261f.a736ea","type":"ui_template","z":"73ac3c27.dcfd64","group":"99b10eed.f26b","name":"","order":0,"width":0,"height":0,"format":"\n<iframe src=\"{{msg.payload}}\"></iframe>","storeOutMessages":true,"fwdInMessages":true,"templateScope":"local","x":420,"y":240,"wires":[[]]}]
```

Comment: Hello @hardillb. I tried with `<iframe src="{{msg.payload}}"></iframe>`  but in the dashboard I can see: Cannot GET /ui/%7B%7Bmsg.payload%7D%7D

Comment: I have the same problem with the working example: `Cannot GET /ui/%7B%7Bmsg.payload%7D%7D` . I am using Node-Red v0.20.5 and Node-Red dashboard 2.16.3 Do you have any idea? Thanks

Comment: Nope, it's working fine on NR 0.20.7 and Dashboard 2.16.3